# IIS8 Won't update web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I have a web site being hosted on a Windows Server 2012 using IIS8. I had modified some code and uploaded it to the server and then restarted the website. The problem is, the old code is executing!

I have:

- Restarted the IIS Server
- Rebooting Windows Server 2012
- Disabled Output Caching for the site.
- Disabled Output Caching for the entire server
- Removed and readded the website.

I even opened the code file in notepad on the server and confirmed that it IS the new code. The old code, to my knowledge, doesn't exist on the server! What am I missing?

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you checking it on the server or could it be that the client browser has cached any pages?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try attaching the visual studio debugger to the instance of IIS and see if you can hit some breakpoints in the old/new code.

To Do this in visual studio.

1. Click "Debug" from the menu bar
2. Click "Attach to Process"
3. Check the "Show processes from all users" checkbox in the bottom left corner
4. Select aspnet_wp.exe from the process list
5. Click "Attach"

If the code does not match between the code in visual studio and the code, you will not be able to set a breakpoint. However, if the code is the same, you will be able to attach and breakpoint and follow the flow of the execution.

Also, have you checked if the DLL's are deployed to the GAC (Global Assembly Cache)? If a .dll exists in both locations on the windows box the application will always pull the version that is in the GAC.